# Salvar modo de encerramento da aplicação

Tags: c#

Tenho o seguinte cenário:

1 aplicação que roda em 10 máquinas, onde quando a aplicação está executando fica em `on-line` e quando não está, aquela máquina fica como `off-line`, que se comunica com um banco de dados *SQL* para informar seu Status.

O problema é: Se cair a energia?

Pensei em ficar salvando em `txt` o `status` a cada 10 segundos por exemplo, e quando ligar o PC consultar essa informação, mas não sei se é a melhor forma,
alguém tem alguma ideia melhor?

Comment: Cara pra esse caso aí, se entendi bem o seu problema, o ideal é usar a abordagem cliente servidor. Onde as aplicações que rodam nas 10 máquinas sejam servidoras. Assim você usará um cliente para verificar se essas máquinas estão online ou off-line e o cliente é que fará a atualização do status no banco de dados.

Comment: Gustavo, consegue nos dar mais informações de como está funcionando? Essa aplicação está situada em cada máquina não em um servidor? Quando o programa inicia ele solicita a atualização do status para online (update em uma tabela), e quando ele encerra ele faz uma nova solicitação porém agora para offline é isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá!

Existem N formas de fazer isso, vou dar umas dicas.

Se você tem a comunicação com o banco de dados via aplicação, pode fazer algo bem simples que é um ping. Você grava de tempos em tempos que a sua aplicação está online, portanto você saberá via banco isso.

Exemplo: Tabela status_micros(id_micro,ultimo_ping);

Você saberá quando foi o último ping dela, portanto saberá se ela está off ou não.

Outra solução seria fazer este mesmo conceito ping porém utilizando uma comunicação p2p para obter a informação.

Pode criar um micro rest, aonde você via protocolo http envia uma requisição para a sua aplicação perguntando se ela está offline.

Ainda existem outras inúmeras soluções para isso.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Olá Felipe, Obrigado pela resposta, perdoa a minha demora para dar um retorno.

Então acho que não expliquei corretamente, um computador pode estar ligado, logado na aplicação mas off-line, se a energia cair, como vou saber quem estava off e on?
Vou fazer pelo banco mesmo, crio uma tabela e salvo a STS de geral a cada um certo tempo, quando cair pego o essa tabela, obrigado man.